# Call specific method of a managed bean from a menu item with prime faces

Tags: jsf-2, menu, primefaces, menuitem, menubar

I have a JSF2 page build with with Primefaces. In this page I have a menu bar which contains below code, having 3 menu items: File -> Open, Create, Quit.

```
<p:menubar styleClass="ui-menuitem-link">
  <p:submenu label="File" icon="ui-icon-document">
    <p:menuitem value="Create" icon="ui-icon-contact" url="fileCreate.jsf" />
    <p:menuitem value="Open" url="fileOpen.jsf"  />
    <p:menuitem value="Quit" url="#" />
  </p:submenu>
</p:menubar>
```

I have a problem regarding the Quit menu item. Here I when user wants to logout he used to click on Quit menu item. And for login-logout purpose I have separate session scoped UserServiceBean managed bean which contains methods

```
public String login();
public String logout();
public boolean isUserLoggedIn();
public String register();
```

So I got stuck what should the url I provide in menuitem, so that I can directly call UserServiceBean.logout() method and the logged in user will get logout by this service bean. I tried by providing action and actionListener attribute for p:menuItem, but it didn't help.

Comment: This should work:   <p:menuitem value="Quit" action="#{UserServiceBean.logout}" ajax="false" /> //assuming your bean name is called  UserServiceBean and you have implemented the logoutMethod. Your menubar also needs to be in a form

Comment: Thanks it worked, actually the problem was menu items were not in form.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<p:menuitem id="id"
value="Your Menu Text"
icon="fa fa-user"
actionListener="#{yourManagedBean.youtMethod}"/>
```

Comment: And why like this? Care to elaborate?